# JAR register BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, jar, broadcastreceiver

My BroadcastReceiver class name is `net.push.MyReceiver`

and the Mainfest in JAR:

```
<receiver android:name="net.push.MyReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="MyReceiver_Action" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and the register BroadcastReceiver,Receiver can not receive broadcast.

if i change the Mainfest like below:

```
<receiver android:name="net.push.MyReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="MyReceiver_Action" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

then it can Receive the broadcast.

I wonder  how can i Receive the broadcast while register the mainFest in JAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AndroidManifest.xml is specified for an application not for a jar.
So, if you want your receiver to actually work, you need to put that declaration in application manifest which should be located in the root of your application project folder.

> Every application must have an AndroidManifest.xml file (with
>   precisely that name) in its root directory

More to read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html